# Click Handler not working on OpenLayers Map in Ubuntu

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, ubuntu, osx

This is really strange as the problem seems to be persisting on the Ubuntu OS itself. I have created a WMS and it works fine on Mac and Windows, but not on Ubuntu.

I have a simple WMS which is returning the Lat & Long for the location on the map where the user does a single click. It seems that on Ubuntu (all the browsers), the map gets dragged when clicked once.

Is this a bug?? is it becoz i m using Ubuntu 12.04??

Comment: **UPDATE**

It seems that this problem is not just specific to OpenLayers, even Google maps cannot register click event on it's Map. WHAT IS THIS PROBLEM???

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: It is not the browser issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug up all the places also contacted all the folks I know who use Ubuntu. It seems that it is working fine on their system. So finally I was able to understand that it is VMware Fusion, which is causing this problem. Sorry not OpenLayer or Browser, but VMWare Fusion running on Mac OS X.